# Mask a class D IP address

Tags: networking, ip-address

[Last time I asked](https://superuser.com/questions/289310/class-d-ip-address) about masking class D ip addresses. I found that we cannot mask class D IP addresses. But, now I have another question about masking D class IP addresses:

If I want to recieve a multicast video on my PC and I try to cofigure a Multicast IP address (such as 224.0.0.1 or another class D IP address), what mask should I use?

If it is impossible to mask class D IP addresses, what should I do else?

Comment: By the way, your example, 224.0.0.1, is the all-hosts multicast address. All machines already get traffic at that address. If you ping that address, you'll get replies from all the machines in the same broadcast domain as your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "configure" multicast addresses the same way as unicast. The operating system usually has separate functions for joining a multicast group using IGMP: on Linux you can use `ip maddr add 224.0.0.1 dev eth0`. Generally, the program should join multicast groups itself, without special configuration.